# Create new DOM elements with children elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create following elements

```
<span>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
</span>
```

I want to do above using jquery in following manner.

```
$('<span />', {
}).appendTo('body');
```

**How can I create children element of span with above method?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/w63FF/)</kbd>

```
$('<span />', {})
    .append($('<h3/>').text('Tite'))
    .append($('</p>').text('para'))
    .appendTo('body');
```

---

or

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/w63FF/2)</kbd>

```
$('<span />', {})
    .append(function () {
    return '<h3>Title</h3><p>This is paragraph</p>';
}).appendTo('body');
```

---

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/w63FF/3)</kbd>

```
$('<span />', {})
    .append($('<h3/>').text('Tite'), $('</p>').text('para'))
    .appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve above the first one without too many appends and also no concatination?

Comment: OK then what about if I have another `span` inside `p`? How would I achieve that using the first method?